# Selenium - NG-IF or Next Element?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm developing a VBA web scraper for internal intranet using Selenium and am stuck extracting a couple pieces. I have had good luck in accessing most of the data using CSS but have run into a couple cases where the class is commonly used and the location of the certain element may vary.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 header-section header-list">

<li>
    <i class="hire-icon-contactcard-outline header-list-icon"></i>
    <span class="modal-link ng-binding" data-ng-click="createContactCardModal()">View full contact card</span>
</li>

<li>
    <i class="hire-icon-email-outline header-list-icon"></i>
    <!-- ngIf: !candidate.hasEmailAddress() -->
    <!-- ngIf: candidate.hasEmailAddress() -->
    <a href="mailto:testemail@gmail.com" ng-if="candidate.hasEmailAddress()" class="ng-binding ng-scope">testemail@gmail.com</a>
    <!-- end ngIf: candidate.hasEmailAddress() -->
</li>

<li>
    <i class="hire-icon-phone-solid header-list-icon"></i>
    <!-- ngIf: !candidate.hasPhoneNumber() -->
    <!-- ngIf: candidate.hasPhoneNumber() -->
    <span ng-if="candidate.hasPhoneNumber()" class="ng-binding ng-scope">123-456-7898</span>
    <!-- end ngIf: candidate.hasPhoneNumber() -->
</li>
```

I have been trying a variety of the following and feel like I'm somewhat close but know my code is likely off.

```
CandidateEmail = bot.FindElementByCss("[class$='hire-icon-email-outline header-list-icon']/following-sibling::[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'])")

CandidateEmail = bot.FindElementByXPath("//i[@class='hire-icon-email-outline header-list-icon']/following-sibling::a[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'])")
```

Any idea what I might be missing? Additionally, is it possible to simply have selenium select the ngIf element - such as

Thanks in advance for your time and insight! It's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a css attribute = value selector combination with ^ starts with operator to target the email element by its href value.

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[href^=mailto]")
```

You could further specify, if needed, adding an additional attribute selector (or indeed swopping the second for the first in the above):

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[href^=mailto][ng-if='candidate.hasEmailAddress()']")
```

Also, consider an adjacent sibling combinator where you specify the a tag after the email icon.

```
bot.FindElementByCss(".hire-icon-email-outline ~ a")
```

---

Here is one potential application of substring matching

```
Dim dict As Object, key As Variant
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "hasEmailAddress", vbNullString
dict.Add "hasPhoneNumber", vbNullString

For Each key In dict.keys
    On Error Resume Next
    dict(key) = bot.FindElementByCss("[ng-if*=" & key & "]").Text 'assuming no illegal characters in string
    Debug.Print key, bot.FindElementByCss("[ng-if*=" & key & "]").Text
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

Comment: I appreciate the response - I'd rather not use something specific to find the href as this is a common challenge throughout the website and not just specific to the email address. As an example, even trying to find the phone number in the given code I have to follow the same method. I tried using the adjacent sibling combinator and it isn't working.

Comment: They have a similar structure so you can have a list substrings and concatenate those in during a loop

Comment: Did you try the edit as css selectors should be faster method.

Answer (score 0):

In the css selector looks like you're mixing the syntax for XPath in there; and both examples will probably get tripped up by the space in your class name.  I would use:

```
CandidateEmail = bot.FindElementByCss(".hire-icon-email-outline.header-list-icon")
```

the initial dot tells it to look for elements with the specified class name, and you need to replace the space in the class with a dot, otherwise it will be considered as two classes.

Oh, I've just noticed you are looking for the 'a' element which should be able to be located by the following (if that is the entirety of the HTML):

```
CandidateEmail = bot.FindElementByCss("a.ng-binding.ng-scope")
```

Or (again if what you've posted is the whole HTML), there is only one 'a' element in there, meaning the following should work:

```
CandidateEmail = bot.FindElementByCss("a")
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, the format that works for other selectors is `CandidateName = bot.FindElementByCss("[class$='candidate-name ng-binding']").Attribute("innerText")` Using just the ng-binding.ng-scope doesn't work as it's commonly used throughout the rest of the html. This is just a very small code snippet out of the full code. The first example doesn't work. I tried adding .Attribute("innerText") to the end and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Well I’m going to have a hard time specifying any unique selector unless I see the full HTML. If you post all your html I’m sure you’ll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had everything I needed, just needed to play with it more.

Was able to get it working through the following

```
CandidateEmail = bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@ng-if='candidate.hasEmailAddress()']").Attribute("innerText")
```